# JQuery fade .not() divs, remove fade when other selected

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am trying to set up a 'team' page on a site. I want the functionality to be as follows.

Click "Image A" and "Bio A" shows. Click "Image B" and "Bio A" closes, "Bio B" opens. I also want the non-active images to fade so that you can see what bio goes with which headshot. I have it all working, everything is responsive with flexbox. The fade works on the *first* click instance, but then I need to get rid of the "non-selected" class on the image of the newly selected click. Lastly, if *no* bio's are open/selected, all fades should go away.

New to jQuery, everything I've tried has not worked. The *last* line is what my best guess was to fix, but didn't do the trick. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<script>   
$("a").click(function(e) {
    var tClass = $(this).attr("id"),
        content = $("div.toggles." + tClass),
        link = $(this);

    //fades any 'toggle' class without selected id
    $("div.toggles:not('." + tClass + "')").fadeOut("fast");

    //fades any image/'a' that is NOT the clicked one
    $("a").not(link).addClass( "non-selected" );

    content.fadeToggle("fast", function() {});
    e.preventDefault();

    //trying to remove fade on selected image/'a'... removeClass didn't work either
    $("a('#" + tClass + "')").addClass( "bio-selected" );

}); 
</script>
```

I also tried some things similar to the following, without luck.

```
//fades any image/'a' that is NOT the clicked one
$("a").is(link).removeClass( "non-selected" );
```

**Structure:**

```
<div class="name profile overlay">
    <a href="#" id="c8"><img></a>
</div>

<div class="name-bio bio toggles c7">
```

**CodePen:** http://codepen.io/markrutt/pen/XbvMez

Thank you for any help/widsom!

Comment: Could you please add ur code snippet in plunker ? It will be easy to help

Comment: here's a pen - hope this helps. thank you @Jagadesh K http://codepen.io/markrutt/pen/XbvMez

Comment: Also, when all bio's are closed, the fades should be removed from all images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you can find a more elegant way to do this, but you can simply add / remove the classes on every link and **then** process `this` as needed. Add the following to the top of your click handler and you'll see what I mean.

```
$("a").removeClass( "bio-selected" );  
$("a").addClass( "non-selected" );  

$(this).removeClass( "non-selected" );  
$(this).addClass( "bio-selected" );
```

There are better ways to do this. This is simply for demonstration.

**CodePen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOeJYG

**Edit:** As pointed out, this doesn't remove the fade when the bio is closed. You can easily solve that with an if/else statement.

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    var link = $(this),
        tClass = link.attr("id"),
        content = $("div.toggles." + tClass);

    // We can assume the user wants to close the bio
    // if it already has the `bio-selected` class
    if (link.hasClass( "bio-selected" )) {
      // Reset every link
      $("a").removeClass( "non-selected bio-selected");  
    } else {
      // Set every link as `non-selected` and then
      // set the proper classes for `this` link
      $("a").removeClass( "bio-selected").addClass( "non-selected");  
      link.removeClass( "non-selected").addClass( "bio-selected");
    }

    // Fade any 'toggle' class without selected id
    $("div.toggles:not('." + tClass + "')").fadeOut("fast");

    // Needed to show content
    content.fadeToggle("fast", function() {});

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Updated CodePen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOeJYG

Comment: awesome @Stef --- I knew it was a matter of me overcomplicating, or putting something in the wrong place. This definitely achieves most of what I am looking for. Is there any way to remove the "non-selected" class when you exit out of the bio's all together  -- ex: clicking a name twice. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MrkRtt I've updated my answer. I'll leave the jumpy transition for you to figure out, but the bio behaviour should be good to go.

Comment: brilliant! thanks @Stef, this just saved me a world of headaches. totally makes sense when I see it. much appreciated!